# WWW::Google::PageRank always returns undef

Tags: perl

I am trying to run the following code:

```
 use WWW::Google::PageRank;
 my $pr = WWW::Google::PageRank->new;
 print scalar($pr->get('http://www.yahoo.com/'));
```

Why does it return the `undef` value with every site?

When I debugged the HTTP::Request, I get 404. It is worth it to mention that I am not behind a proxy.

Answer (score 7):

That page rank module is quite old, are you sure this API is still supported by Google?

The [Perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/~ykar/WWW-Google-PageRank/lib/WWW/Google/PageRank.pm) says it will query `http://toolbarqueries.google.com/` by default. That gets me a HTTP 404 page not found error. The Perldoc says this will result in the `undef` you are seeing.

Wikipedia says on [page rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Google_Toolbar) that Google removed this API in 2016, which fits the observed behavior.

Long story short: don't use the WWW::Google::PageRank module.

Comment: Hi Robert do you know if there are any alternative ?

Comment: @jsor I don't know, but I doubt it, if Google retired the API.

Comment: There are several online tools that give you something like that, but nowadays PageRank is not the only tool to compute the placement of a result on Google; there are many filters, and lots of things to take into account. I think Google AdSense does have some tools to compute how pages are ranked according to search queries, but nowadays there's nothing as simple as that.